# How do I remove the italics on the words in my navigation bar?

Tags: html, navigationbar

On all the other pages of the website the navigation bar is in normal font but for some reason the font on the home page nav bar is in italics. I've completely forgotten how to make it so it doesn't have italics or where to search to change it so please help

http://surbaisse.com/index.html

```
#tabsJ {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  background:#F4F4F4;
  font-size:93%;
  line-height:normal;
      border-bottom:1px solid #24618E;
  }
#tabsJ ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 10px 0 50px;
    list-style:none;
    text-align: center;
  }
#tabsJ li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }
#tabsJ li a:hover {
  background color: #111
  }
#tabsJ a {
  float:left;
  background:url(file:///C|/Users/xw4600/Documents/Bugatti Dave/tableftJ.gif) no-repeat left top;
  margin:0;
  padding:0 0 0 5px;
  text-decoration:none;
  }
#tabsJ a span {
  float:left;
  display:block;
  background:url(file:///C|/Users/xw4600/Documents/Bugatti Dave/tabrightJ.gif) no-repeat right top;
  padding:5px 15px 4px 6px;
  color:#24618E;
  }
/* Commented Backslash Hack hides rule from IE5-Mac \*/
#tabsJ a span {float:none;}
/* End IE5-Mac hack */
#tabsJ a:hover span {
  color:#FFF;
  }
#tabsJ a:hover {
  background-position:0% -42px;
  }
#tabsJ a:hover span {
  background-position:100% -42px;
  }

    #tabsJ #current a {
            background-position:0% -42px;
    }
    #tabsJ #current a span {
            background-position:100% -42px;
            color:#FFF;
    }
```

Comment: please, post the code you use to create the navbar...

Comment: Ok I updated it

Answer (score 0):

You are using `<em>` it makes your text italic.Your markup structure is not good.

Add in your css on  #tabsJ `font-style: normal;`

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your site, the reason the text is in italics is because you put it in an `<em>` tag. As you can see on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_em.asp), `<em>` makes any string between it's opening and closing tags emphasized, making them appear as italics.

Remove the 3 `em` blocks from under `#Layer3`.

Also, and please, don't take this the wrong way, but your HTML-structure is horrible. Please, consider rebuilding your site's structure so it will be easier to maintain in the future.

For example, `em` is an [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) type element, while `div` is a block type element. Putting block elements in inline ones, while not impossible, should be avoided. It makes building maintainable structure and sane CSS harder, and only leads to headache, tears and swearing in the future.

Comment: Haha I see thank you; and yes, I know, the website's structure is pretty messy but it was done by someone else and I am just trying to make it visually look... better (if possible with my little to none skill lol)